# Preventing iframe postback from calling jQuery 'ready' function on parent

Tags: jquery, iframe, postback, tabs

I have an an iframe within a jQuery tab layout. I am using the iframe to upload an image, to simulate a AJAX file upload. It seems whenever my iframe postbacks, it causes the parent page's $(document).ready to execute, resetting the current tab I am positioned on.

Any ideas on how to prevent this?

```
    function uploadDone() {

    var data = eval("("+ $('#upload_target').contents().find('body').html() +")");
    if(data.success) {
       $('#upload_summary').append("<img src='" + data.full_path + "' />");
       $('#upload_summary').append("<br />Size: " + data.file_size + " KB");
    }
    else if(data.failure) { //Upload failed - show user the reason.
        alert("Upload Failed: " + data.failure);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#image_uploader').submit(function() {

        if($.browser.safari || $.browser.opera) {

            $('#upload_target').load(function(){
                setTimeout(uploadDone, 0);
            });

            var iframe = document.getElementById('upload_target');
            var iSource = iframe.src;
            iframe.src = '';
            iframe.src = iSource;

        } else {

            $('#upload_target').load(uploadDone);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Could you post your code? Can't you try to set a flag when you submit form on iFrame and check that flag in document.ready of your parent page?

Comment: Is it normal behaviour that a postback in an iframe, cause a postback in the parent page though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A flag makes sense (as what SolutionYogi mentioned). If the document.ready in the parent frame is only required to execute once, set a global flag to a value which you can check when it got fired again.

Another way is to unbind document.ready after executing it.
E.g. `$(document).unbind('ready')`